# How to use what st.file_uploader returns with Streamlit?

Tags: python-3.x, input, streamlit

I'm reusing some old code but i'm trying to make it look better by using Streamlit. I'm adding a file_uploader with which I want to upload a CSV file.

After this, I want to read the first 11 lines of that file to determine how to process it (my files are not necessarily all identical).

However, with Streamlit, the file_uploader returns a byte-like file and therefore I can't use the "i.readline())" nor the next part of the code in which I'm looking at what the file startswith.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks!

```
def Generate_dashboard():
    ifile = st.file_uploader("Upload your CSV file here!", type="CSV",accept_multiple_files=False)
    if ifile is not None:
        with open(ifile, 'rb') as i:
            ln = 0header = []
            while ln < 11:
                header.append(i.readline())
                ln += 1
            if any("CGTR" in s for s in header):
                T = 1.e-3
            else:
                T = 200.e-6
            if header[0].startswith("#Version:"):
                data = np.genfromtxt(ifile, delimiter=",", skip_header=6, skip_footer=1, names=True) # Skip 6 first lines with header.
            elif header[0].startswith("#discard="):
                data = np.genfromtxt(ifile, delimiter=",", skip_header=1, skip_footer=1, names=True)
            elif header[0].startswith("beamline id = "):
                T = 250.e-6data = np.genfromtxt(ifile, delimiter=",", skip_header=10, skip_footer=7, names=True) # Skip 9 first lines with header.
            else:
                skip = int(input("\nUnknown log format. How many header lines to cut before the channel names? "))
                data = np.genfromtxt(ifile, delimiter=",", skip_header=skip, skip_footer=1, names=True)
```